# Condition on $h$ ensuring that $e^{-(c(h-k))^2}<\varepsilon$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z$

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function

Let $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$ and $c>0$. Note that $$\varphi(x):=e^{-(cx)^2}<\varepsilon\Leftrightarrow|x|>\frac{\sqrt{-\ln\varepsilon}}c\tag1$$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Now let $h\in(-1,1)$.

> Can we determine a condition (a bound) on $h$ such that whenever this condition is satisfied, then $\varphi(h-k)<\varepsilon$ **for all** $k\in\mathbb Z$? Or will there always be a $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\varphi(h-k)\ge\varepsilon$?

By $(1)$, $$\varphi(h-k)<\varepsilon\Leftrightarrow|h-k|>\frac{\sqrt{-\ln\varepsilon}}c\tag2$$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z$, but this is not helpful. Maybe we can use the reverse triangle inequality, which yields $$|h-k|\ge||h|-|k||=|k|-|h|\tag3$$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$. Now, for $k\in\mathbb Z$, $$|k|-|h|>\frac{\sqrt{-\ln\varepsilon}}c\Leftrightarrow|h|<|k|-\frac{\sqrt{-\ln\varepsilon}}c\tag4.$$

### **EDIT**

From $(4)$ we should be able to conclude that (assuming $-\ln\varepsilon\le c^2$) if $$|h|<1-\frac{\sqrt{-\ln\varepsilon}}c,\tag5$$ then all $k\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ satisfy $(2)$. On the other hand, if $$|h|>\frac{\sqrt{-\ln\varepsilon}}c\tag,6$$ then $(2)$ is satisfied for $k=0$. In conclusion, a possible condition should be $$\frac{\sqrt{-\ln\varepsilon}}c<|h|<1-\frac{\sqrt{-\ln\varepsilon}}c\tag7.$$ Or did I made any mistake?

### **EDIT 2**

I did not, but (obviously) no such $h$ exists (since the left-hand side is at least 1 and the right-hand side is smaller $1$). So, this approach is not helpful.

Comment: Consider $k=0$, eq $(2)$ becomes: $|h|>\frac{\sqrt{-\ln\varepsilon}}c = \sqrt{-\frac{\ln\varepsilon}{\ln e^{c^2}}}$.
Take $c=\sqrt\varepsilon>0$, the RHS becomes $\sqrt{\frac{-\ln\varepsilon}\varepsilon}$ which goes to $+\infty$ as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$. Thus there is no $h\in(-1,1)$ satisfying $(2)$ for $k=0$.

Comment: @GFrazao Thank you for your comment. Note that $c$ and $\varepsilon$ are fixed. So, I cannot choose them. Moreover, I would like to have a condition on $h$ such that if that condition is fulfilled, then there is no $k\in\mathbb Z$ satisfying $(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is equivalent to
$$[h-a,h+a]\cap\Bbb Z=\varnothing,\text{ where }a=\frac{\sqrt{-\ln\varepsilon}}c,$$
i.e.
$$\exists n\in\Bbb Z\quad n+a<h<n+1-a.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean that if $$\exists n\in\Bbb Z\quad n+a<h<n+1-a$$ is satisfied, then $\varphi(h-k)<\varepsilon$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z$?

Comment: If so, how would I need to check this (efficiently) numerically in a computer program?

Comment: 1) Yes, this is what I proved above (not only if, but if and only if). 2) No idea, but this is another question.