# Numerically check whether, given $h$ and $a$, there is a $ n\in\Bbb Z$ with $n+a<h<n+1-a$?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Let $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$ and $c>0$. Note that $$\varphi(x):=e^{-(cx)^2}<\varepsilon\Leftrightarrow|x|>\frac{\sqrt{-\ln\varepsilon}}c\tag1$$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Now let $h\in(-1,1)$.

> I need to numerically verify in a computer program whether $$\varphi(h-k)<\varepsilon$$ **for all** $k\in\mathbb Z$? It is crucial to perform this test as efficient as possible.

As explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4654404/47771), the desired condition is equivalent to $$\exists n\in\Bbb Z\quad n+a<h<n+1-a.\tag1$$ Unfortunately, I have no idea how we can check this efficiently.

Comment: A necessary condition is $a<\frac12.$

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? You know $a>0$ and $h\in(-1,1)$, right? Why can't you check eq. $(1)$ efficiently? ``1)`` if $a\geq\frac12$ return ``fail``, ``2)`` let $n=\lfloor h\rfloor$ and check eq. $(1)$.

Comment: Finally, why don't you accept/upvote the answers you were given? Is there anything you still don't understand? Or are you not thankful to the anonymous user freely giving their freetime to help you?

Answer (score 0):

The existence of such an $n$ is equivalent to
$$h+a<\lceil h-a\rceil$$
and also to
$$\lfloor h+a\rfloor<h-a.$$